# HERE Geocoding API - not working inside my React app

Tags: reactjs, geocoding, here-api

I have a React app in which I use the HERE Geocoding API. I have an axios request to retrieve latitude and longitude and it does not work as well as expected. The request is not working inside my app

```
return axios.get(`https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=${address}&apiKey=myAPIKey`)
```

I have a 401 error. `Bearer token invalid. Bearer missing or bearer value missing.` If I open a new tab in my browser and paste the url `https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=${address}&apiKey=myAPIKey` it works fine and I get the result I need.

I tried using the Authorization header

```
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `apiKey myAPIKey`,
        }
    };
    return axios.get(`https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=${address}&apiKey=myAPIKey`,config)
```

In the Authorization header, I tried with `Bearer` and `Basic` instead of apiKey

[documentation HERE API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html)

In the documentation about how to create an API Key and how to use it, the only thing I need to do is what I have already done. I have created a project, an API Key and I use it in my request.

[HERE Geocoding API Key](https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/dev-apikey.html)

Comment: Hi, would you please try to set header to  "headers: { }" ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the HERE api works but the error message is probably the answer you are looking for.

You are likely to provide the api key via the Authorization header with your request. Read about the header on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)

Comment: It says that my Bearer token is invalid but I don't have any bearer token... I tried adding the Authorization header with both Basic and Bearer using my API key as value but it does not work. The api key should be enough, shouldn't it ?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/dev-apikey.html
1: Register your app - I have created my project,
2: Get an API Key - I created the API key,
3: Use the API Key - I can use it directly in the browser but not in my app

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass your API key in the link as a parameter.
Just sign up and you can get your API key.
https://developer.here.com/sign-up

The code should be like this.

```
return axios.get(`https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=${address}&apiKey=${HERE_MAP_API_KEY}`,config)
```

The latest request would look like this.

```
axios.get(`https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/search/6.2/geocode.json?languages=en-US&maxresults=${maxResults}&searchtext=${query}&apiKey=${HERE_MAP_API_KEY}`)
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data
      console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```